# Filter out empty array emmited by observable subscription

Tags: rxjs

I'm using the `combineLatest` operator to get value from two observables. Both observables initially emit empty arrays. I want to filter that out. For non array scenarios we can pipe `filter(data => !!data)` like this omit the empty values. Is there any way to do the same for empty arrays?

```
loadData(){
 this.subscription.add(
    combineLatest([this.companyType$,this.countryType$]).subscribe((data) => {
       //intially i get [Array(0), Array(0)].i want ommit this. 
     })
   );
}
```

Comment: `filter(data => data.length)`

Comment: The solution provided by @ThomasSablik should work. But perhaps a little more explanation: Numeric `0` is falsy in Javascript, `!!0` is `false`. So in your case, initially since the array the empty, `data.length` must be `0` which could be checked against for an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.subscription.add(
  combineLatest(this.companyType$, this.countryType$).pipe(
    filter(([foo, bar]) => foo.length > 0 && bar.length > 0)
  ).subscribe();
);
```

Something like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

If both streams emit an empty array to start with then you could also skip the first emission from `combineLatest`:

```js
const x$ = interval(100).pipe( startWith([])
                             , map(n => [n+10])
                             , take(10));
                             
const y$ = interval(200).pipe( startWith([])
                             , map(n => [n+20])
                             , take(10));
                             
const z$ = combineLatest([x$, y$]).pipe( skip(1) /* <-- HERE */
                                       , map(([[x], [y]]) => [x, y]));

z$.subscribe(n => console.log(`n=${n}`));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.2.0/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-MlqMFvHwgWJ1vfts5fdC2WzxDaIXWfYuAd9Tb2lobtF61Gk+HIRDrbtxgasBSM9lZgOK9ilwK9LqFIYEV+k0IA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
const { interval, combineLatest } = rxjs;
const { startWith, map, take, skip } = rxjs.operators;
</script>
```